# Download and open a pdf within Xamarin Android app?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am trying to download and open a PDF file from a URL in Xamarin Android. I can open the URL no problem, which of course saves the PDF in the Downloads folder. Is there a way I can then access that same file and have it open automatically after being downloaded within my app? Here is how I am currently opening the URL to download:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView, Uri.Parse("http://sampleURL.com"));

StartActivity(browserIntent);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would first have to know the name of the file that was download.

Then you could do this

```
var filename = "file.pdf";
var file = System.IO.Path.Combine(Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDownloads).ToString(), filename);
var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(file);

Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionView);
intent.SetFlags(ActivityFlags.ClearTop);
intent.SetDataAndType(uri, "application/pdf");
try
{
    StartActivity(intent);
}
catch (ActivityNotFoundException e)
{
    Toast.MakeText(Application.Context, "Install a pdf viewer.", ToastLength.Long).Show();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering! I wound up just opening the PDF with the default PDF viewer app since I was accessing it with a URL, but this will come in handy when we go a different route.

Comment: **From Android 7, this solution will not work you have to use** `FileProvider`

Comment: @Abdurakhmon can you provide a full working example, please?